# How to boot from a usb stick when using U-Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I am trying to install ubuntu arm onto my Mac M1 Arm but once I get to uboot I have absolutely no clear why to boot from my usb-stick that has a bootable ios installed on it.

I assume its possible to boot from a usb stick?

[image]

Is it possible to install ubuntu from an external USB stick via u-boot?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu ARM will **NOT** work on a M1 Mac, because of the gigantic porting effort needed

If you want to run Linux on your M1 Mac, there is the [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/), but this is still in alpha

Comment: Thank you! This is actually using Asahi Linux boot loader. With `https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/`. But the bigger question is just, can you boot with uboot?